# How to get request body of a HttpServeletRequest at debug time in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any good way to get the request body of a javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest while debugging in IntelliJ? The class I am debugging is not under my control. I am debugging the decompiled code in IntelliJ and would like to see the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no straight forward way to do that, but in a case, if you just want to watch the body of the request, you can use code below within your method :

```
Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println( s.next());
        }
```